# Installing Nuget package is working in .net framework but not working in .net core application

Tags: nuget, .net-core-3.1

I have one package in our artifactory that include Font, Image folder. when i install that package in .Net Framework application, I can see Font folder and Image Folder created inside Application but when i download same package to my .net core application, not able to see those folder. just i can see package inside dependencies folder.
Any help appreciated

Comment: What does your package manager log/console say?

Comment: It says Successfully Installed '......'

Comment: And also i can see all font and image name inside Project.assets.json under obj folder. but problem is not creating folder for Image and font inside wwwroot folder.

Comment: Does the package you are installing have `content` or `contentfiles` folder?

`content` is packages.config, `contentFiles` is PackageReference and all of .NET Core projects are PackageReference based

Comment: when i saw package those are installing in .net framework has content folder not ContentType.